# OpenSSH sshd.exe does not start with KexAlgorithms parameter

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys, sshd, jenkins

Running OpenSSH Server 8.1p on Windows Server 2016 DC

When I add the parameter "KexAlgorithms" in the sshd_config, the service fails to start. I want to add legacy support for key methods below, for jenkins 'wagon-ssh' plugin trying to ssh to a server node to deploy content.

```
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Service works fine without that parameter, and I can't seem to find definitive documentation that they deprecated this sha1 support which disables the service from starting or maybe Windows is not letting it start?

Edit: have also tried just the one algorithm thats needed by client

```
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

Comment: Do you need all of them? Usually just one is enough (group14 in most cases). Does sshd log anything when it fails to start, either to Event Log or to a file in C:\ProgramData? Can you try running `sshd -t` or `sshd -T`?

Comment: yes, the client is only offering group-exchange-sha1 and group1-sha1 so i tried each of those by themselves.